# What is correct javascript function to get a iframe

Tags: javascript

When I developed a FB application, I tried to get the canvas used javascript like below:

#### Work

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1].id
//Output: iframe_canvas
```

#### Not Work

```
window.frames[1].id
//Output: undefined
```

I don't know why, after that I looked for the answers on SO, I found the answer and comment for my issue.

> [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page#251453)

But, I really don't understand `why`:

> You can't use "window.frames" if your IFRAME was created programmatically, only if it is declared in the HTML page source. Src [@Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)'s comment

Comment: Don't know why someone voted down my question too?

Comment: isn't it illegal because of CSRF?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe it was because the title of your post has a question that seems to be answered by the body of your post, and you pose no further question(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because browsers have implemented this in such a way. Things like `window.frames` were never a part of any standard. This is one of the reasons why they are inconsistent and poor sometimes.